# Can * be used for partial topics in AWS' IoT Rule syntax?

Tags: sql, aws-iot

Is this allowed as AWS' IoT Rule syntax?:

```
SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/truck*/shadow/update/accepted' WHERE state.reported.truck_type <> "pickup"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use a `*` to achieve this, since you must pass a valid topic filter.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html#topicfilters) you are able to use a `+` sign to achieve this effect.

Quoted from the documentation linked above:

> A subscription to sensor/+/room1 receives messages published to sensor/temperature/room1 and sensor/humidity/room1, but not messages sent to sensor/temperature/room2 or sensor/humidity/room2.

Comment: But not "truck*"...  In other words, if I only want to consider my different "truck" Things (Things that are named "truck1", "truck40", etc.) and not my "car" Things, I cannot achieve such filtering.

Comment: Indeed. You can restructure your topic hierarchy to have the ID (if you can call it that) on a different level to support this use case.

Comment: If you could elaborate, how do I create such "levels"?  When I create a new Thing in the AWS web console, it is at the same hierarchical level as anything else I created.

Comment: I didn't clock it was a shadow topic that you were using. Indeed, with things, this is not possible, since this is also not really designed to do this. You could work around this, by having a "type" identifier (or something similar) in the state of the thing, and use it in the WHERE clause. But this is a workaround and might not be the best solution depending on your use case.

Comment: I see.  I have only worked with AWS IoT Things, so I am unfamiliar with using "topics" in any other way.  Thank you.